# How to call function in c++ which return a class object to c#

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

C# function calls the exposed function in c++ which in-turn calls class abc's some_fun(int), how should i get the object of abc in C# some_fun `enter code here`

C++:

```
class abc
{
    public: abc some_fun(int x);
}
```

this function calls class abc's some_fun(int),
how should i get the object of abc in C# some_fun (marshalled object)

```
extern "C" SAMPLEDLL_API void __cdecl some_fun(int x);
```

from c# wrapper: how to i marshal it

```
public static extern IntPtr some_fun(int abc);
```

Comment: Hows about serializing it to JSON on the c++ side and then deserializing it on the c# side to the object you want?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to "Pinvoke" your c++ function from you C# program.
When you do this, you'll have to declare your function signature in C# terms.
In that declaration, you'll have to give a C# struct represnting the C++ struct you trying to pass.

for example, if you have the C++ struct:

```
struct FOO
{
public long Dummy;
};
```

In your C# program, you'll have to define a C# struct

```
public struct CSFOO
{
public int Dummy;
}
```

which you'll pass to your PINVOKEd function.

This link can help you:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx